# $\mathbb{R}^{n}-A$ is path-connected for any countable subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness, path-connected

I have the following result along with the proof. I want to generalize this to $n$-dimension.

**Result**  Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be countable. Then $\mathbb{R}^{2}-A$ is path connected.

Proof. Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}-A .$ since there are only countably many points in $A,$ there are only countably many lines through $x$ that hit $A .$ similarly, there are only countably many lines through $y$ that hit $A .$ Therefore there are at least two lines through $x$ that do not hit $A$ and one line through $y$ that does not hit $A$. (Actually, there are uncountably many, but this is all we need.) Then the line through $y$ must intersect one of those two lines through $x$ in a point $z .$ We can then form a path from $x$ to $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}-A$ by taking the union of the line segment from $x$ to $z$ with the line segment from $z$ to $y$ and appropriately parameterizing this geometric construction to form a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.

Now can I generalize this proof? i.e. I want to show that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be countable, then also $\mathbb{R}^{n}-A$ is path-connected.

Comment: Seems like you should just replace every $2$ with $n$ and line by hyperplane in essence. I guess claiming that the amount of planes that that $A$ is countable is less trivial though.

Comment: Simply take any 2-dimensional subspace of $R^n$ containing 2 arbitrary points and apply your above result.

Comment: Assume $x\ne y$. Pass a plane through $x$ and $y$. There are continuum many circles in that plane which pass through $x$ and $y$, and no point in $A$ (in fact no point in $\mathbb R^n$ except $x$ and $y$) lies on more than one of those circles, so there is a circle which passes through $x$ and $y$ and is disjoint from $A$. Thus any two points in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ are connected by a circle arc in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$.